# Simple route for mvc not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a very simple normal route and I can't seem to get it to work. I'm kind of clueless what I'm missing.

My routing is:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

My Controller is called AccountController and it has this method:

```
 public virtual ApplicationUser EditUser(String userId)
```

I post this URL and I get a userid that is null

```
 /Account/EditUser/Patrick
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your route has a parameter called "id", whereas your method has a parameter called "userId". These need to match.

So either create a route, like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "EditUser",
        url: "Account/EditUser/{userId}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "EditUser"});
```

Or change your method to be:

```
public virtual ApplicationUser EditUser(string id);
```

Note that if you choose the first option, you need to put that call *before* the existing default one, because any URL you enter will match against the *first* route which matches it.

Comment: Thanks m8. Feel kind off stupid. Too long out of MVC programming and only backend stuff made me forget this simple thing :(